# what is the difference between ndk-build and make APP for android?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am having too many confusions in native coding for android. My application wants to play mms:// stream and I'm facing some serious problems in that. But the basic question is

**What is the difference between ndk-build**  (that i usually use) **and make APP** (i have seen many blogs on them one of them is [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html))

Another related question

Suppose my project is in E:\WorkSpace\mmsTests\AnotherMMS (*path edited if you want to test : it contained whitespace*)
And my ndk path is D:\android-ndk-r4b-windows\android-ndk-r4b

**How can i use make APP with cygwin?**
My os is windows xp sp2.

**EDIT** : I have added ndk location in my PATH variable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'make APP=...' method was the original NDK build system but is now deprecated in favor of the ndk-build method.

Anything that can be built with make APP=xxx can be built with ndk-build. ndk-build requires less manual setup and hard coded paths.

Comment: Heartly thanks, one more little curiosity. Is ndks are linked with sdks? my ndk is r4b, can i target my application for 1.6 device while i'm building my app with this ndk?

Comment: @MobileDev123 - yes. The NDK reads the target platform in the file default.properties. Set it to `target=android-4` for 1.6.